# Easiest way to show total number of subpages

Tags: php, templates, loop, page-template

I am making a portfolio site where each portfolio entry is a subpage of "Work". In my template, I am trying to say something like: worked on 15 projects and counting, where 15 is the total number of subpages.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code, replacing the number after "child_of=" to the id of the parent page.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$pages = get_pages('child_of=681&depth=1');
  foreach($pages as $page) {
    $count++;
  }
  echo $count;
?>
```

Reference: [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I'd upvote but I don't have enough rep points yet. I'll get you back.

Answer (score -1):

```
$pages = get_pages('child_of=681&depth=1');
$count = count($pages);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Agreed. While correct, this provides no instruction. Anyone can copy a codebit.